# Apache Rewrite: Always use HTTPS (how to add an exception)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

On mydomain.com, I currently keep all of my apache conf files in:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

In there I have a file called alwaysHttps.conf that contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I have a bunch of virtualhosts, and for one domain on the site: myotherdomain.com I would like to turn off the auto redirect.  Is it possible to setup an exception to the redirect to https, rather than having to get rid of the global alwaysHttps.conf?

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot /home/webadmin/myotherdomain.com/html 
    ServerName myotherdomain.com 
    CustomLog "/home/webadmin/myotherdomain.com/access_log" "combined" 
    ErrorLog "/home/webadmin/myotherdomain.com/error_log" 
    <Directory /home/webadmin/myotherdomain.com/html> 
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !myotherdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

Comment: OK - perfect! Thanks...

That solves the redirect issue, but now I am getting 404s. My conf file for the domain is:

If I leave off your fix and change the :80 to :443 pages the pages load.  But the way it is now, they don't.  Any quick thoughts?

Comment: Have you got both `NameVirtualHost *:80` & `Listen 80` somewhere in your config?

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic!

In my http.conf I have:

```
NameVirtualHost  *:80
NameVirtualHost  *:443

Listen 8033
```

The reason for the listen on 8033 was because I am using OpenVPN's feature to dual use port 80.  Once I changed my

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  to 
<VirtualHost *:8033>
```

everything worked.

The curious thing though is why all of my other virtual domains and *.conf files work even though they have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

and not

```
<VirtualHost *:8033>.
```

Any idea why that would be the case?